# ¿Como subir archivos junto con formularios en angular usando como back-end django

Tags: python-3.7, djangorestframework, angular12

Buenas nosé cómo subir archivos, estado intentando pero no sé cómo pasárselo al back end  agradecería que me dieran un ejemplo.

Vale pues mira tengo lo siguiente, yo consulte en [esta pagina](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-file-upload/) lo hice con base en esta pero el problema es que cuando lo voy a enviar me sale este error en el servidor, `"La información enviada no era un archivo. Compruebe el tipo de codificación del formulario. "` estoy seguro que es la parte de front-end porque probe la api con posman y me sirvió

```
export class FormularioNovosComponent implements OnInit {
 

  form :FormGroup;
 
  constructor(private cd:ChangeDetectorRef,private fb:FormBuilder,private service:ServiceService,private router:Router,private activvarRoute:ActivatedRoute) {
    
    this.form=this.fb.group({
      id:[],
      acta:['',Validators.required],
      fechaSolicitud:['',Validators.required],
      aprendizNovedad:['',Validators.required],
      tipoNovedad:['',Validators.required],


    })
   }
   
   datosDetalle !:novedad 

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id','acta','fechaSolicitud','aprendizNovedad','tipoNovedad'];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activvarRoute.params.subscribe(e=>{
      let id=e['id'];
        if(id){
         this.service.getNovedadesdid(id).subscribe(res=>{
            this.datosDetalle = res[0]
           this.form.setValue({
             'id':this.datosDetalle.id,
             'acta':this.datosDetalle.acta,
             'fechaSolicitud':this.datosDetalle.fechaSolicitud,
             'aprendizNovedad':this.datosDetalle.aprendizNovedad,
             'tipoNovedad':this.datosDetalle.tipoNovedad
           })
           console.log(res)
          })
        }
    })
  
  }

  agregar(form:novedad){
    console.log(form)
    if (form.id> 0) {
      console.log(form)
      this.service.updatenove(form).subscribe(p=>{
        this.router.navigate(['novedad'])        
      })
    }else{
     var p = new FormData()
       const tpnovedad:novedad={
      id:this.form.value.id,
      acta:this.form.value.acta,
      tipoNovedad:this.form.value.tipoNovedad,
      fechaSolicitud:this.form.value.fechaSolicitud,
      aprendizNovedad:this.form.value.aprendizNovedad
    }

    this.service.agregarNovedad(tpnovedad).subscribe(
      res=>{console.log(res)})
    }
   
  }
  filechange(event:any){
    var file= event.target.files
    let reader= new FileReader()
    if(event.target.files && event.target.files.length){
        const [file]=event.target.files 
       
        reader.readAsDataURL(file)
        reader.onload=()=>{
          this.form.patchValue({ 
            acta:reader.result
          })
          this.cd.markForCheck()
          console.log(file)
        }
      
    }
  }
}



//Formulario


<mat-card>
   
  
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="agregar(form.value)"  > 
    
        <input type="hidden"  value="0" formControlName="id">
        <mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="90px">
            <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="1" [rowspan]="2" >
              
               
                    <mat-label style="padding: 0.5rem;">acta</mat-label>
                    <input name="file" type="file" (change)="filechange($event)">
                    <input #acta class="matInput" formControlName="acta" type="hidden"  placeholder="Upload file" >
                 
            </mat-grid-tile>


            <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="1" [rowspan]="2" >
                <mat-form-field class="ancho">
                    <mat-label>fecha Solicitud</mat-label>
                    <input matInput type="date" formControlName="fechaSolicitud" />
                  </mat-form-field>  
            </mat-grid-tile>




            <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="1" [rowspan]="2" >
                <mat-form-field class="ancho">
                    <mat-label>aprendiz Novedad</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="aprendizNovedad" />
                  </mat-form-field>  
            </mat-grid-tile>



            <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="1" [rowspan]="2" >
                <mat-form-field class="ancho">
                    <mat-label>Tipo Novedad</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="tipoNovedad" />
                  </mat-form-field>  
                </mat-grid-tile>

            <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="2" [rowspan]="2" >
                <button type="submit"  [disabled]="form.invalid" mat-raised-button style="margin-right: 20px;" color="primary">Aceptar</button>
                <button mat-raised-button color="warn">Cancelar</button>
            </mat-grid-tile>

      </mat-grid-list>
    </form>
</mat-card>
```

vale la primera function es para capturar el archivo, y la de agregar es para enviar los datos hacia el archivo de service, el primer bloque que esta condicionado por el if es para actualizar pero no importa por ahora, perdonaran si encuentran algo ilógico es que soy nuevo, acepto sugerencias gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente lo que estas preguntando.

Comment: súbelos por ajax

Comment: Christian cómo lo subo? Porque es que estoy trabajando con Django rest framework y angular en la parte de front-end

Comment: Hola, agrega por favor lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Vale pues mira tengo lo siguiente, yo consulte en esta pagina https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-file-upload/  lo hice con base en esta pero el problema es que cuando lo voy a enviar me sale este error en el servidor ,"La información enviada no era un archivo. Compruebe el tipo de codificación del formulario. " estoy seguro  que es la parte de front-end  porque probe  la api con posman y me sirvió

Comment: Todo eso debe estar en la pregunta editada y agrega eso

Comment: Recuerda que ajax es un método de comunicación entre cliente y servidor. Existen diversas formas de implementarlo en tu frontend, ya sea usando `fetch` que es nativo de JS, JQuery o Axios

Comment: Y como es tu frontend?? Que es o que tienes??